# Protractor "stale element reference: element not attached... How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Am able to get to the proper page no problem using `browser.get()`.  I then `get.all(by.TagName('a'))` for the links and click on the first one, browser goes there no problem.   This statement returns the promise with new URL...

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {  //I can see proper new page url here..}
```

I get a stale page error on the expect statement below... contained within the callback above is this:

```
describe('new page url', function(){
     it('should do something', function(){
        expect(url == "http://SomeValueAlreadyKnown");
     } 
});
```

Please advise me on what I'm doing wrong.  How to click on links and avoid stale page errors?

Comment: also its `expect(actualValue).toEqual/toBe(expectedValue)` with jasmine.

Comment: Ah... maybe that's the root cause, I'm not even doing syntax correctly?  Let me try that and post back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In protractor `expect()` is "patched" to resolve promises implicitly, you can just do:

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("http://SomeValueAlreadyKnown");
```